# Update package-manager to include programs installed from source

Tags: package-management, software-installation, source

I am installing aircrack-ng from source using the instructions given in their [official website](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack&DokuWiki=fef2e783083e330677d01079ce6f00ed). However when I am finished installing, I run:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep aircrack-ng
```

Or:

```
apt-cache policy aircrack-ng
```

Both are showing that the package is not installed. However when I type:

```
aircrack-ng
```

at the shell it shows a list of aircrack-ng options. So that I am sure that it is installed. But as it is not installed from the official repositories via apt-get it is not getting included in the package manager.

My questions:

1. How to include the application in `apt-get` or `aptitude` package manager that I install from source?
2. Commands to view the list of all packages installed from source but has not been included in the package manager?
3. In Windows I get a list of all installed programs in the Control Panel, irrespective of the way they are installed. What is the equivalent command in Linux? `dpkg --get-selections` returns a huge list that seem not only to contain all list of applications, but also drivers. I want just the applications names. What command do I issue?

Comment: No, In windows you will not see any portable application. They act as like never been installed.

Comment: Don't ask too many questions.please make it to a single one.

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to view  packages which are installed from source through `aptitude or dpkg or apt-cache or synaptic`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own ***deb*** package using `apt-get source`.

```
karimov-danil@Karimov-Danil:~$ apt-get source aircrack-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 1 721 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe aircrack-ng 1:1.1-6 (dsc) [1 849 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe aircrack-ng 1:1.1-6 (tar) [1 453 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe aircrack-ng 1:1.1-6 (diff) [266 kB]
Fetched 1 721 kB in 11s (146 kB/s)                                             
gpgv: Signature made Вт. 11 июня 2013 06:45:57 YEKT using RSA key ID 9FFA69A3
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./aircrack-ng_1.1-6.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting aircrack-ng in aircrack-ng-1.1
dpkg-source: info: unpacking aircrack-ng_1.1.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking aircrack-ng_1.1-6.debian.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying 000-Airmon_needs_bash.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 002-Fix_airodump-ng_manpage.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 003-fix-ftbfs-590765.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 004-fix-license-issues.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 005-fix-issues-cppcheck-r2008.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 006-fix-ftbfs-and-man-path.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 008-fix_path_airodump-ng-oui.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 009-airodump-ng-oui-update-manpage.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 010-add-freebsd-support.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 011-add-support-for-gcrypt.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 012-add-unittest-gcrypt.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 013-fix-hurd-ftbfs.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 014-man_page_formatting.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 015-move_to_man8_admin_commands.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 016-fix-ldflags.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 017-fix-bigendianissues.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 018-workaround-681113-kfreebsd.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 019-fix-spelling-manpages.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 020-ignore-negative-one.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying 021-fix-airodump-ng-oui-update.diff
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev
cd aircrack-ng-1.1/
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

This will make deb file which is installable by `dpkg`.

```
sudo dpkg -i ../aircrack-ng_1.1-6_amd64.deb
```

After installation you will see it inside Synaptic under Local and Obsolete Packages.

[image]

Answering to the second question, Avinash Raj is correct. There is no way you can see all applications installed in non-standard ways. The same situation as with portable applications in Windows.

And how to see all installed applications? Open Dash and choose Applications Lens.

[image]

The command `xdotool key super+a` and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> are equivalent and show the above panel. Before applying this command, you have to install `xdotool` package. Install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

And if you want to retrieve applications list, use following command:

```
 ls /usr/share/applications/ | sed s/.desktop// -
```